# How to fill the LinearLayout row?

Tags: android

I using LinearLayout as a table that need to contain 3 column. 
I need to feel up the row an i don't know how to do it from the code in run time.

```
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Cell1"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Cell2"
     android:layout_width="70dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Cell3"
     android:layout_width="60dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Cell1); textView.setText("whatever");` How about that as a short example ? Or you mean you to create and fill the row with TextViews ?

Comment: there are 3 column ... i need to fill all of them in the row

Comment: yes - i want to fill up dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that produces layout equivalent to what you have declared in your .xml
You could put it somewhere in your activity (so `this` refers to your activity)

```
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.setPadding(0, 4, 0, 6);
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        // creating and setting the cells now

        // cell 1
        TextView cell1 = new TextView(this);
        // convert dip into pixels for LayoutParams constructor 
        // as it only understands px
        int widthPix1 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        row.addView(cell1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                widthPix1, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        // cell 2
        TextView cell2 = new TextView(this);
        int widthPix2 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                70, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        row.addView(cell2, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                widthPix2, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

        // cell 3
        TextView cell3 = new TextView(this);
        int widthPix3 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                60, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        row.addView(cell3, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                widthPix3, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
```

As you can see the amount of code is significantly bigger than when your layout is in .xml and you simply inflate with

```
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
```

And I can hardly imagine a situation when you want to do it the way you asked for.

Anyways, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

My advice if I got you right:

```
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Cell1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="5"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Cell2"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="7"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/Cell3"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_weight="6"/>

</LinearLayout>
```